# How to call outer class arguments inside inner class?

Tags: python, class

Hello I'm quite a beginer at using classes in python. I'm trying to get Outer class arguments parameters inside Inner class. For example I have :

```
class Rectangle: 

  n_edges = 4

  def __init__(self, length, width):
    self.length = length
    self.width = width

  def rectangle_area(self):
    return self.length*self.width


  def rectangle_perimeter(self):
    return 2*self.length + 2*self.width
    
  class Patch:
    
    def __init__(self, cor1, cor2):
      self.cor1 = cor1
      self.cor2 = cor2
      # I want here to get length and width
```

So I want to have length and width arguments of Rectangle class in the Patch class without passing them as parameters in the constructor of Patch

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: first of all why would `Patch` class be nested inside `Rectangle`? Is it that you want `Patch` to inherit from `Rectangle`?

Comment: Why are you nesting the classes to begin with?

Comment: "So I want to have length and width arguments of Rectangle class in the Patch class without passing them as parameters in the constructor of Patch" why dont you want to pass them as arguments?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen there is absolutely *not* a parent-child relationship between those two classes

Comment: Are you coming from Java? Python doesn't have nested inner classes. Putting a class definition inside another class definition simply outs one class in the namespace of another, which really doesn't change anything except how you can *access* the class

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen **it is definitely not a parent-child** relationship. That means inheritance in Python, unequivocally. In any case, I already stated exactly that in my previous comment.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen there is no special name for this relationship. One object exists in the namespace of another object. This is no different than `x.y = y`. One class is an attribute of another class. So I guess "is an attribute of" would actually describe the relationship.

Comment: There a few benefits from nesting classes in Python — they don't have special access to theire outer class and are often awkward to work with.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I wanted to define a function get_next_patch() in the Patch class in order to have for a given patch (defined by its coordinates) the next patch so that I could call something like : Rectangle(5,5).Patch(2,3).get_next_patch()

Answer (score -1):

At first save the python file with first class i. e save the rectangle class in a python file (rectangle. Py). Then in other python file import rectangle. py file, so you can use all the functions of rectangle class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer would be more helpful if you posted a code example.